# Problem with creating structural modules using interfaces (SystemVerilog)

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I'm new in SystemVerilog, and currently learn interfaces, and I ran into problem with structural modules.
So, for example, i have created interface

```
interface BusInterface
#(parameter N = 3) (input logic i_clk);
logic               i_RESET;
logic               i_in;
logic               counterClock;
logic[(N - 1):0]    o_count;
logic               o_ERROR;


modport DetectorInterface
    (input  i_RESET,
    input   i_in,
    output  counterClock,
    output  o_ERROR);

modport CounterInterface
    (input  i_RESET,
    output  o_count);

modport FallingsCounterInterface
    (input  i_RESET,
    input   i_in,
    output  o_count,
    output  o_ERROR);

modport StimulatorInterface
    (output i_RESET,
    output  i_in,
    input   o_count);

modport MonitorInterface
    (input  i_RESET,
    input   i_in,
    input   counterClock,
    input   o_count,
    input   o_ERROR);

modport CommonInterface
    (input  i_RESET);

endinterface
```

I also created 2 modules:

```
module FallingEdge_Detector
(BusInterface.DetectorInterface interfaceDetector);

int k;
typedef enum logic[1:0] {s_NewCountCycle, s_ReadyToCount, s_EndCountCycle}  stateType;
stateType               currentState, nextState;


//  Register logic
always_ff @(posedge interfaceDetector.i_clk, posedge interfaceDetector.i_RESET)
begin
    if (interfaceDetector.i_RESET)  currentState <= s_NewCountCycle;
    else if (interfaceDetector.i_clk)   currentState <= nextState;
end

//  Next State logic
always_comb
begin
    case (currentState)
        s_NewCountCycle:
        begin
            if (interfaceDetector.i_in) nextState <= s_ReadyToCount;
            else                        nextState <= s_NewCountCycle;
        end
        s_ReadyToCount:
        begin
            if (interfaceDetector.i_in) nextState <= s_ReadyToCount;
            else                        nextState <= s_EndCountCycle;
        end
        s_EndCountCycle:
        begin
            if (interfaceDetector.i_in) nextState <= s_ReadyToCount;
            else                        nextState <= s_NewCountCycle;
        end
    endcase
end

//  Output logic
assign interfaceDetector.counterClock = (currentState == s_EndCountCycle);
assign interfaceDetector.o_ERROR = (currentState != s_EndCountCycle) &
(interfaceDetector.counterClock == 1'b1);

endmodule


module Counter
#(parameter N = 3) (BusInterface.CounterInterface interfaceCounter);

int k;


//  Register logic
always_ff @(posedge interfaceCounter.i_clk, posedge interfaceCounter.i_RESET)
begin
    if (interfaceCounter.i_RESET)   k <= 0;
    else if (interfaceCounter.i_clk)    k <= k + 1;
end

//  Output logic
assign interfaceCounter.o_count = k[(N - 1):0];

endmodule
```

The problem is that I cannot create a top-level module:

```
module FallingsCounter
#(parameter N = 3) (BusInterface.FallingsCounterInterface interfaceFallingsCounter);
/*
(input logic                i_clk, i_RESET,
input logic                 i_in,
output logic[(N - 1):0]     o_count,
output logic                o_ERROR);
*/

logic                           counterClock;


FallingEdge_Detector Detector
    (interfaceFallingsCounter.i_clk, interfaceFallingsCounter.i_RESET,
        interfaceFallingsCounter.i_in,
        counterClock,
        interfaceFallingsCounter.o_ERROR);
    Counter Counter
    (counterClock, interfaceFallingsCounter.i_RESET,
        interfaceFallingsCounter.o_count);

endmodule
```

When I try to make this in that way, i get the next errors:

```
Error (10285): Verilog HDL Module Instantiation error at FallingsCounter.sv(28): instance "Detector" specifies 5 actual port connections but module "FallingEdge_Detector" only expects 1
Error (10978): SystemVerilog error at FallingsCounter.sv(25): unknown type and interface type are not equivalent - equivalent types must have same number of bits
Error (10698): SystemVerilog error at FallingsCounter.sv(25): can't connect expression with incompatible data type to formal "interfaceDetector"
Error (10181): Verilog HDL Module Instantiation error at FallingsCounter.sv(25): too many ports used in Module Instantiation
Error (10181): Verilog HDL Module Instantiation error at FallingsCounter.sv(26): too many ports used in Module Instantiation
Error (10181): Verilog HDL Module Instantiation error at FallingsCounter.sv(27): too many ports used in Module Instantiation
Error (10181): Verilog HDL Module Instantiation error at FallingsCounter.sv(28): too many ports used in Module Instantiation
```

So, I have the question: how to create the top level module using interface?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use modports in your top-level module port declaration unless they are going to be connected to the same modport in the lower level modules.

Modports are like sub-types passed through an interface port. They define access rights to a bundle of signals, and you cannot change the modport type one it is passed into the module.

What you can do is pass the full interface (without modports) through the top-level module